# Reverting a div to its original state

Tags: jquery, animation

I am new to Jquery, as in this is basically the first time using it, I have been reading up the documentation for what I need to do and I have got stuck.

**HTML**

```
<div class="commercialpopup">
    <p class="close-div">x<p>
    <p><a href="blueindex.php">Go to Commercial</a></p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.commercialpopup {
    background-color: #038CDB;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-right: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-top: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 0 0 20px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #888888;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 54px;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 31px;
    width: 158px;
    z-index: 9999;
    transition: border-color 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: border-color 0.5s linear;    /* FF3.7+ */
    -o-transition: border-color 0.5s linear;      /* Opera 10.5 */
    -webkit-transition: border-color 0.5s linear; /* Saf3.2+, Chrome */
}

.commercialpopup a{
    color: #FFF;
    transition: color 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: color 0.5s linear;    /* FF3.7+ */
    -o-transition: color 0.5s linear;      /* Opera 10.5 */
    -webkit-transition: color 0.5s linear; /* Saf3.2+, Chrome */
}

.close-div{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: right;
}

.close-div:hover{
    color: #999999;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.commercialpopup:hover{
    border-bottom: 4px solid #007BCA;
    border-right: 4px solid #007BCA;
    border-top: 4px solid #007BCA;
}

.commercialpopup a:hover{
   text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

**Jquery**

```
$(".close-div").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut( "slow" );
});

//this is the part I need help with
$( "div.commercialpopup" ).hover(function() {
    $( this ).animate({
        width: "200px",
        fontSize: "1.1em",
    }, 1500 );
});
```

What I need to do is make it so that when the mouse is not hovering over the div, it goes back to its original CSS via reversing the animation.
I know this probably seems pretty easy, but I am stuck and have been for a few hours.
I have looked at `.mouseover/.mouseout` as well as `.addclass/.removeclass` but I couldn't get those two methods to work either.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ymS28/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ymS28/2/)

**JS**

```
$( "div.commercialpopup" ).hover(function() {
     $( this ).animate({
      width: "200px",
      fontSize: "1.1em",
  }, 1500 );
},
 function() {
  $(this).animate({width: "158px",
            fontSize: "1em",
   }, 1500 );
 });
```

Comment: Yeah this works, cheers bud, appreciate it. Quick follow up question, if you hover over it say 5 times quickly it will play the animation 5 times, how do I stop that? I remember reading something like .removequeue?

Answer (score 1):

when you use hover, you can provide two functions, the first when mouse is on element, the second when it leaves it, so it'd be like

```
$( "div.commercialpopup" ).hover(function() {
    $( this ).animate({
        width: "200px",
        fontSize: "1.1em",
    })
  }, function() {
        //change back to normal code
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "div.commercialpopup" ).mouseenter(function() {
 $( this ).animate({
     width: "200px",
     fontSize: "1.1em",
 }, 1500 );
 });

$( "div.commercialpopup" ).mouseleave(function() {
$( this ).animate({
    width: "100px",
    fontSize: "1em",
}, 1500 );
});
```

Just use mouseleave to return the div to its original size.

EDIT: you could also use CSS3 for this, google for transition and animation.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already suggested, you need to maintain the original state of the div. Look at this piece of code.

```
var originalStyle = window.getComputedStyle(this, null);
$('div.commercialpopup').mouseover(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    width: '200px',
    fontSize: '1.1em'
  }, 1500 );
});

$('div.commercialpopup').mouseout(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    width: originalStyle.style['width']
    fontSize: originalStyle.style['font-size']
  }, 1500 );
});
```

Comment: I like the use of getComputedStyle()  +1... but its important to note that it will only work in IE 9+.  All the other browsers support it for the most part. You can reference here for browser compatability http://caniuse.com/getcomputedstyle

Comment: @JohnHartsock Thanks for the link. Coincidently I was reading about the same on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle. IE is the biggest challenge in web dev life ;)

Answer (score 0):

Store the original CSS values you intend to animate, that way you can change the styles and it won't affect the animations as the values aren't hardcoded:

```
$("div.commercialpopup").each(function() {
    $(this).data({width: $(this).css('width'), font: $(this).css('font-size')});
}).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).animate({
            width: "200px",
            fontSize: "1.1em",
        }, 1500);
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).animate({
            width: $(this).data('width'),
            fontSize: $(this).data('font'),
        }, 1500);    
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ymS28/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to remember the previous state of the object prior to executing the hover.   You could use the .data() feature of jQuery to remember the previous state of the object.  The example I provide only requires you to maintain the hoverstate in code.  and pulls the original state from your css.

Here is a fiddle showing my example and below is the code for the example

http://jsfiddle.net/ymS28/12/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".close-div").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().fadeOut( "slow" );
    });

    $( "div.commercialpopup" ).hover(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.animate((function () {
            //Initialize the hoverState
            if (!$this.data("hoverState")) {
                $this.data("hoverState", {
                    width: "200px",
                    fontSize: "1.1em",
                });
            }
            //Get hoverState
            var hoverState = $this.data("hoverState");
            //Set HoverState
            $this.data("hoverState", { width: $this.width(), fontSize: $this.css("font-size") });
            //return hoverstate to the .animate() function
            return hoverState;
        })(), 1500);
    });
});
```